# Change the Cell color

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In iphone application I have an UITableView and whenever I tap on any cell, the cell background color changed to blue color and my text color disappeared.

So my requirement is whenever I tap on a cell, the cell background color does not change to blue, so that my text keeps showing.

Please Give me the answer

Answer (score 1):

to remove blue color as selection style use -

```
[cellView setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: Whenever we are using this code,blue color will not apper at any time.But i want to blink the blue color when u click on any cell of table.So please provide u have any answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn of the selection color by using

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: Whenever we are using this blue color will not apper at any time.But i want to blink the blue color when u click on any cell of table.So please provide u have any answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

To remove blue color write in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method:-

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: Whenever we are using this code, blue color will not apper at any time.But i want to blink the blue color when u click on any cell of table.So please provide u have any answer for that.